# JFrame not closing when it should

Tags: java, swing, serialization, jframe

This code segment is called upon in the making of the JFrame, and when it reaches the dispose() line it does not close. I know it is getting into that block because the other JFrame does open, the only problem is that it is not closing. Anybody know why?

```
    public LogIn(String title)
{
    super(title);
    checker = new Open("");
    deserializeOpen();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 300);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.orange);
    Login = new JButton("Login");
    Create = new JButton("New Profile");
    Login.addActionListener(this);
    Create.addActionListener(this);
    buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setBackground(Color.orange);
    buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
    buttons.add(Login);
    buttons.add(Create);
    Title = new JLabel("Scrambler");
    Title.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24));
    Name = new JTextField(4);
    name = new JLabel("Name:");
    password = new JPasswordField(4);
    pass = new JLabel("Password:");
    Text = new JPanel();
    Text.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,0));
    Text.setBackground(Color.orange);
    Text.add(Title);
    Text.add(name);
    Text.add(Name);
    Text.add(pass);
    Text.add(password);
    getContentPane().add(Text, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    show();
}
    public void deserializeOpen()
{
    try
    {
        FileInputStream door = null;
        try
        {
            door = new FileInputStream("Check.ser");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            new Activator();
            dispose();
        }
        if(door!=null)
        {
         ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(door);
         checker = (Open) reader.readObject();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();}          
}
```

these are just two segments of the code, the body is the first part and the deserialize one is the one that is causing the problem

I'm pretty sure that the dispose() line is being reached because I just put a System.out.print() right about and below the dispose() and both printed out

Comment: Sounds like something is block the EDT or the frame's `DefaultCloseOperation` is set to `DO_NOTHING`...

Comment: Just checked. The DefaultCloseOpeation is set to EXIT. How would one go about fixing something blocking the EDT? I'm a complete newbie.

Comment: It's difficult to know based on the code snippet.  You could take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Read through all of that, not going to lie, it didn't really help but thanks anyway. I decided to try something and this is interesting. I'm not sure if it means anything but when I run the program straight from eclipse it works and closes exactly like it is supposed to. It's only when I export it to a .jar that it doesn't work. Does that mean anything?

Comment: Nevermind, the problem is now happening no matter how I start the program

Comment: It looks like the control of you program moves to the Activator Window and doesn't comes on `dispose()`. Just do one thing switch the line put `dispose()` before the `activator` instance. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I would say @VighaneshGursale is right. Are you 100% sure it reaches `dispose()`? Also if you added `WindowListener` to JFrame it could block closing.

Comment: @Vighanesh I switched them and the problem is still occurring

Comment: @Piro No I'm not so sure anymore. It's reaching the activator for sure but could it be skipping dispose()? And WindowListener can't be the problem because I did not add it

Comment: According to my knowledge the jframe should get close before the activator window starts. I'm not sure what you did but whenever the program control moves to another line it actually performed the previous line (i.e. code). Even the control structure don't move to next line until and unless an exception or that line of code get performed.

Comment: But wouldn't it still close by that logic? Because the Activator instance is only starting a new Activator, it's not waiting for the Activator to do something, so shouldn't it start the Activator the immediately move to the next line a close because of the dispose()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor of your JFrame subclass, you call `deserializeOpen()` first, which disposes the frame (no effect since it's not shown yet), and then call `show()` which opens the frame. So you may have intended to *open-close*, but instead your code *close-opens*.

By the way: the `show()` method is deprecated since JDK1.5, you should use `setVisible(true)` instead.
I'd recommend that you propagate the exceptions in `deserializeOpen()` and catch them outside, that way you can decide whether or not to open the frame instead of opening and closing it:

```
public void deserializeOpen() throws Exception { ... }
```

in the constructor:

```
try {
  deserializeOpen();
  setVisible(true);
} catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStacktrace(); // or any other error handling
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked great. And I did not know that, thank you I won't use show() now.